# Label faceted surf in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a series of X,Y,Z points and like to create a discrete surf plot and label each point. I am using `\addplot3[surf...]` to generate the plot but I can't figure out how to label the colors. I don' want to use `colorbar` and have a continous legend. Rather I want a legend with five discrete colors, labeled 1,2,3,4,5...

I'm not tied to using `\addplot3[surf...]` either.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width = .75\textwidth,height=0.25\textheight, 
view ={0}{90},
xmin=0,
xmax=5000,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-2000,
ymax=2000,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0,
zmax=5,
zmajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=0},
legend entries={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,
colormap/jet,
mesh/rows=11]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false] {%
%
0   -2000   1\\
0   -1950   1\\
0   -1900   1\\
0   -1850   1\\
0   -1800   1\\
0   -1750   1\\
0   -1700   1\\
0   -1650   1\\
0   -1600   1\\
0   -1550   1\\
0   -1500   1\\
0   -1450   1\\
0   -1400   1\\
0   -1350   1\\
0   -1300   1\\
0   -1250   1\\
0   -1200   1\\
0   -1150   1\\
0   -1100   1\\
0   -1050   1\\
0   -1000   1\\
0   -950    1\\
0   -900    1\\
0   -850    1\\
0   -800    1\\
0   -750    1\\
0   -700    1\\
0   -650    1\\
0   -600    1\\
0   -550    1\\
0   -500    1\\
0   -450    1\\
0   -400    1\\
0   -350    1\\
0   -300    1\\
0   -250    1\\
0   -200    5\\
0   -150    5\\
0   -100    5\\
0   -50 5\\
0   0   5\\
0   50  3\\
0   100 3\\
0   150 3\\
0   200 3\\
0   250 3\\
0   300 1\\
0   350 1\\
0   400 1\\
0   450 1\\
0   500 1\\
0   550 1\\
0   600 1\\
0   650 1\\
0   700 1\\
0   750 1\\
0   800 1\\
0   850 1\\
0   900 1\\
0   950 1\\
0   1000    1\\
0   1050    1\\
0   1100    1\\
0   1150    1\\
0   1200    1\\
0   1250    1\\
0   1300    1\\
0   1350    1\\
0   1400    1\\
0   1450    1\\
0   1500    1\\
0   1550    1\\
0   1600    1\\
0   1650    1\\
0   1700    1\\
0   1750    1\\
0   1800    1\\
0   1850    1\\
0   1900    1\\
0   1950    1\\
0   2000    1\\
500 -2000   1\\
500 -1950   1\\
500 -1900   1\\
500 -1850   1\\
500 -1800   1\\
500 -1750   1\\
500 -1700   1\\
500 -1650   1\\
500 -1600   1\\
500 -1550   1\\
500 -1500   1\\
500 -1450   1\\
500 -1400   1\\
500 -1350   1\\
500 -1300   1\\
500 -1250   1\\
500 -1200   1\\
500 -1150   1\\
500 -1100   1\\
500 -1050   1\\
500 -1000   1\\
500 -950    1\\
500 -900    1\\
500 -850    1\\
500 -800    1\\
500 -750    1\\
500 -700    1\\
500 -650    1\\
500 -600    1\\
500 -550    1\\
500 -500    1\\
500 -450    1\\
500 -400    1\\
500 -350    1\\
500 -300    1\\
500 -250    1\\
500 -200    5\\
500 -150    5\\
500 -100    5\\
500 -50 5\\
500 0   3\\
500 50  3\\
500 100 3\\
500 150 3\\
500 200 3\\
500 250 3\\
500 300 3\\
500 350 1\\
500 400 1\\
500 450 1\\
500 500 1\\
500 550 1\\
500 600 1\\
500 650 1\\
500 700 1\\
500 750 1\\
500 800 1\\
500 850 1\\
500 900 1\\
500 950 1\\
500 1000    1\\
500 1050    1\\
500 1100    1\\
500 1150    1\\
500 1200    1\\
500 1250    1\\
500 1300    1\\
500 1350    1\\
500 1400    1\\
500 1450    1\\
500 1500    1\\
500 1550    1\\
500 1600    1\\
500 1650    1\\
500 1700    1\\
500 1750    1\\
500 1800    1\\
500 1850    1\\
500 1900    1\\
500 1950    1\\
500 2000    1\\
1000    -2000   1\\
1000    -1950   1\\
1000    -1900   1\\
1000    -1850   1\\
1000    -1800   1\\
1000    -1750   1\\
1000    -1700   1\\
1000    -1650   1\\
1000    -1600   1\\
1000    -1550   1\\
1000    -1500   1\\
1000    -1450   1\\
1000    -1400   1\\
1000    -1350   1\\
1000    -1300   1\\
1000    -1250   1\\
1000    -1200   1\\
1000    -1150   1\\
1000    -1100   1\\
1000    -1050   1\\
1000    -1000   1\\
1000    -950    1\\
1000    -900    1\\
1000    -850    1\\
1000    -800    1\\
1000    -750    1\\
1000    -700    1\\
1000    -650    1\\
1000    -600    1\\
1000    -550    1\\
1000    -500    1\\
1000    -450    1\\
1000    -400    1\\
1000    -350    1\\
1000    -300    1\\
1000    -250    1\\
1000    -200    5\\
1000    -150    5\\
1000    -100    5\\
1000    -50 5\\
1000    0   3\\
1000    50  3\\
1000    100 3\\
1000    150 3\\
1000    200 3\\
1000    250 3\\
1000    300 3\\
1000    350 1\\
1000    400 1\\
1000    450 1\\
1000    500 1\\
1000    550 1\\
1000    600 1\\
1000    650 1\\
1000    700 1\\
1000    750 1\\
1000    800 1\\
1000    850 1\\
1000    900 1\\
1000    950 1\\
1000    1000    1\\
1000    1050    1\\
1000    1100    1\\
1000    1150    1\\
1000    1200    1\\
1000    1250    1\\
1000    1300    1\\
1000    1350    1\\
1000    1400    1\\
1000    1450    1\\
1000    1500    1\\
1000    1550    1\\
1000    1600    1\\
1000    1650    1\\
1000    1700    1\\
1000    1750    1\\
1000    1800    1\\
1000    1850    1\\
1000    1900    1\\
1000    1950    1\\
1000    2000    1\\
1500    -2000   1\\
1500    -1950   1\\
1500    -1900   1\\
1500    -1850   1\\
1500    -1800   1\\
1500    -1750   1\\
1500    -1700   1\\
1500    -1650   1\\
1500    -1600   1\\
1500    -1550   1\\
1500    -1500   1\\
1500    -1450   1\\
1500    -1400   1\\
1500    -1350   1\\
1500    -1300   1\\
1500    -1250   1\\
1500    -1200   1\\
1500    -1150   1\\
1500    -1100   1\\
1500    -1050   1\\
1500    -1000   1\\
1500    -950    1\\
1500    -900    1\\
1500    -850    1\\
1500    -800    1\\
1500    -750    1\\
1500    -700    1\\
1500    -650    1\\
1500    -600    1\\
1500    -550    1\\
1500    -500    1\\
1500    -450    1\\
1500    -400    1\\
1500    -350    1\\
1500    -300    1\\
1500    -250    1\\
1500    -200    2\\
1500    -150    3\\
1500    -100    3\\
1500    -50 3\\
1500    0   3\\
1500    50  3\\
1500    100 3\\
1500    150 3\\
1500    200 3\\
1500    250 3\\
1500    300 3\\
1500    350 3\\
1500    400 1\\
1500    450 1\\
1500    500 1\\
1500    550 1\\
1500    600 1\\
1500    650 1\\
1500    700 1\\
1500    750 1\\
1500    800 1\\
1500    850 1\\
1500    900 1\\
1500    950 1\\
1500    1000    1\\
1500    1050    1\\
1500    1100    1\\
1500    1150    1\\
1500    1200    1\\
1500    1250    1\\
1500    1300    1\\
1500    1350    1\\
1500    1400    1\\
1500    1450    1\\
1500    1500    1\\
1500    1550    1\\
1500    1600    1\\
1500    1650    1\\
1500    1700    1\\
1500    1750    1\\
1500    1800    1\\
1500    1850    1\\
1500    1900    1\\
1500    1950    1\\
1500    2000    1\\
2000    -2000   1\\
2000    -1950   1\\
2000    -1900   1\\
2000    -1850   1\\
2000    -1800   1\\
2000    -1750   1\\
2000    -1700   1\\
2000    -1650   1\\
2000    -1600   1\\
2000    -1550   1\\
2000    -1500   1\\
2000    -1450   1\\
2000    -1400   1\\
2000    -1350   1\\
2000    -1300   1\\
2000    -1250   1\\
2000    -1200   1\\
2000    -1150   1\\
2000    -1100   1\\
2000    -1050   1\\
2000    -1000   1\\
2000    -950    1\\
2000    -900    1\\
2000    -850    1\\
2000    -800    1\\
2000    -750    1\\
2000    -700    1\\
2000    -650    1\\
2000    -600    1\\
2000    -550    1\\
2000    -500    1\\
2000    -450    1\\
2000    -400    1\\
2000    -350    1\\
2000    -300    1\\
2000    -250    2\\
2000    -200    2\\
2000    -150    5\\
2000    -100    3\\
2000    -50 3\\
2000    0   3\\
2000    50  3\\
2000    100 3\\
2000    150 3\\
2000    200 3\\
2000    250 3\\
2000    300 3\\
2000    350 3\\
2000    400 1\\
2000    450 1\\
2000    500 1\\
2000    550 1\\
2000    600 1\\
2000    650 1\\
2000    700 1\\
2000    750 1\\
2000    800 1\\
2000    850 1\\
2000    900 1\\
2000    950 1\\
2000    1000    1\\
2000    1050    1\\
2000    1100    1\\
2000    1150    1\\
2000    1200    1\\
2000    1250    1\\
2000    1300    1\\
2000    1350    1\\
2000    1400    1\\
2000    1450    1\\
2000    1500    1\\
2000    1550    1\\
2000    1600    1\\
2000    1650    1\\
2000    1700    1\\
2000    1750    1\\
2000    1800    1\\
2000    1850    1\\
2000    1900    1\\
2000    1950    1\\
2000    2000    1\\
2500    -2000   1\\
2500    -1950   1\\
2500    -1900   1\\
2500    -1850   1\\
2500    -1800   1\\
2500    -1750   1\\
2500    -1700   1\\
2500    -1650   1\\
2500    -1600   1\\
2500    -1550   1\\
2500    -1500   1\\
2500    -1450   1\\
2500    -1400   1\\
2500    -1350   1\\
2500    -1300   1\\
2500    -1250   1\\
2500    -1200   1\\
2500    -1150   1\\
2500    -1100   1\\
2500    -1050   1\\
2500    -1000   1\\
2500    -950    1\\
2500    -900    1\\
2500    -850    1\\
2500    -800    1\\
2500    -750    1\\
2500    -700    1\\
2500    -650    1\\
2500    -600    1\\
2500    -550    1\\
2500    -500    1\\
2500    -450    1\\
2500    -400    1\\
2500    -350    1\\
2500    -300    2\\
2500    -250    2\\
2500    -200    2\\
2500    -150    5\\
2500    -100    3\\
2500    -50 3\\
2500    0   3\\
2500    50  3\\
2500    100 3\\
2500    150 3\\
2500    200 3\\
2500    250 3\\
2500    300 3\\
2500    350 3\\
2500    400 3\\
2500    450 1\\
2500    500 1\\
2500    550 1\\
2500    600 1\\
2500    650 1\\
2500    700 1\\
2500    750 1\\
2500    800 1\\
2500    850 1\\
2500    900 1\\
2500    950 1\\
2500    1000    1\\
2500    1050    1\\
2500    1100    1\\
2500    1150    1\\
2500    1200    1\\
2500    1250    1\\
2500    1300    1\\
2500    1350    1\\
2500    1400    1\\
2500    1450    1\\
2500    1500    1\\
2500    1550    1\\
2500    1600    1\\
2500    1650    1\\
2500    1700    1\\
2500    1750    1\\
2500    1800    1\\
2500    1850    1\\
2500    1900    1\\
2500    1950    1\\
2500    2000    1\\
3000    -2000   1\\
3000    -1950   1\\
3000    -1900   1\\
3000    -1850   1\\
3000    -1800   1\\
3000    -1750   1\\
3000    -1700   1\\
3000    -1650   1\\
3000    -1600   1\\
3000    -1550   1\\
3000    -1500   1\\
3000    -1450   1\\
3000    -1400   1\\
3000    -1350   1\\
3000    -1300   1\\
3000    -1250   1\\
3000    -1200   1\\
3000    -1150   1\\
3000    -1100   1\\
3000    -1050   1\\
3000    -1000   1\\
3000    -950    1\\
3000    -900    1\\
3000    -850    1\\
3000    -800    1\\
3000    -750    1\\
3000    -700    1\\
3000    -650    1\\
3000    -600    1\\
3000    -550    1\\
3000    -500    1\\
3000    -450    1\\
3000    -400    1\\
3000    -350    2\\
3000    -300    2\\
3000    -250    2\\
3000    -200    2\\
3000    -150    2\\
3000    -100    3\\
3000    -50 3\\
3000    0   3\\
3000    50  3\\
3000    100 3\\
3000    150 3\\
3000    200 3\\
3000    250 3\\
3000    300 3\\
3000    350 3\\
3000    400 3\\
3000    450 3\\
3000    500 1\\
3000    550 1\\
3000    600 1\\
3000    650 1\\
3000    700 1\\
3000    750 1\\
3000    800 1\\
3000    850 1\\
3000    900 1\\
3000    950 1\\
3000    1000    1\\
3000    1050    1\\
3000    1100    1\\
3000    1150    1\\
3000    1200    1\\
3000    1250    1\\
3000    1300    1\\
3000    1350    1\\
3000    1400    1\\
3000    1450    1\\
3000    1500    1\\
3000    1550    1\\
3000    1600    1\\
3000    1650    1\\
3000    1700    1\\
3000    1750    1\\
3000    1800    1\\
3000    1850    1\\
3000    1900    1\\
3000    1950    1\\
3000    2000    1\\
3500    -2000   1\\
3500    -1950   1\\
3500    -1900   1\\
3500    -1850   1\\
3500    -1800   1\\
3500    -1750   1\\
3500    -1700   1\\
3500    -1650   1\\
3500    -1600   1\\
3500    -1550   1\\
3500    -1500   1\\
3500    -1450   1\\
3500    -1400   1\\
3500    -1350   1\\
3500    -1300   1\\
3500    -1250   1\\
3500    -1200   1\\
3500    -1150   1\\
3500    -1100   1\\
3500    -1050   1\\
3500    -1000   1\\
3500    -950    1\\
3500    -900    1\\
3500    -850    1\\
3500    -800    1\\
3500    -750    1\\
3500    -700    1\\
3500    -650    1\\
3500    -600    1\\
3500    -550    1\\
3500    -500    1\\
3500    -450    1\\
3500    -400    1\\
3500    -350    2\\
3500    -300    2\\
3500    -250    2\\
3500    -200    2\\
3500    -150    2\\
3500    -100    3\\
3500    -50 3\\
3500    0   3\\
3500    50  3\\
3500    100 3\\
3500    150 3\\
3500    200 3\\
3500    250 3\\
3500    300 3\\
3500    350 3\\
3500    400 3\\
3500    450 3\\
3500    500 1\\
3500    550 1\\
3500    600 1\\
3500    650 1\\
3500    700 1\\
3500    750 1\\
3500    800 1\\
3500    850 1\\
3500    900 1\\
3500    950 1\\
3500    1000    1\\
3500    1050    1\\
3500    1100    1\\
3500    1150    1\\
3500    1200    1\\
3500    1250    1\\
3500    1300    1\\
3500    1350    1\\
3500    1400    1\\
3500    1450    1\\
3500    1500    1\\
3500    1550    1\\
3500    1600    1\\
3500    1650    1\\
3500    1700    1\\
3500    1750    1\\
3500    1800    1\\
3500    1850    1\\
3500    1900    1\\
3500    1950    1\\
3500    2000    1\\
4000    -2000   1\\
4000    -1950   1\\
4000    -1900   1\\
4000    -1850   1\\
4000    -1800   1\\
4000    -1750   1\\
4000    -1700   1\\
4000    -1650   1\\
4000    -1600   1\\
4000    -1550   1\\
4000    -1500   1\\
4000    -1450   1\\
4000    -1400   1\\
4000    -1350   1\\
4000    -1300   1\\
4000    -1250   1\\
4000    -1200   1\\
4000    -1150   1\\
4000    -1100   1\\
4000    -1050   1\\
4000    -1000   1\\
4000    -950    1\\
4000    -900    1\\
4000    -850    1\\
4000    -800    1\\
4000    -750    1\\
4000    -700    1\\
4000    -650    1\\
4000    -600    1\\
4000    -550    1\\
4000    -500    1\\
4000    -450    1\\
4000    -400    2\\
4000    -350    2\\
4000    -300    2\\
4000    -250    2\\
4000    -200    2\\
4000    -150    2\\
4000    -100    3\\
4000    -50 3\\
4000    0   3\\
4000    50  3\\
4000    100 3\\
4000    150 3\\
4000    200 3\\
4000    250 3\\
4000    300 3\\
4000    350 3\\
4000    400 3\\
4000    450 3\\
4000    500 1\\
4000    550 1\\
4000    600 1\\
4000    650 1\\
4000    700 1\\
4000    750 1\\
4000    800 1\\
4000    850 1\\
4000    900 1\\
4000    950 1\\
4000    1000    1\\
4000    1050    1\\
4000    1100    1\\
4000    1150    1\\
4000    1200    1\\
4000    1250    1\\
4000    1300    1\\
4000    1350    1\\
4000    1400    1\\
4000    1450    1\\
4000    1500    1\\
4000    1550    1\\
4000    1600    1\\
4000    1650    1\\
4000    1700    1\\
4000    1750    1\\
4000    1800    1\\
4000    1850    1\\
4000    1900    1\\
4000    1950    1\\
4000    2000    1\\
4500    -2000   1\\
4500    -1950   1\\
4500    -1900   1\\
4500    -1850   1\\
4500    -1800   1\\
4500    -1750   1\\
4500    -1700   1\\
4500    -1650   1\\
4500    -1600   1\\
4500    -1550   1\\
4500    -1500   1\\
4500    -1450   1\\
4500    -1400   1\\
4500    -1350   1\\
4500    -1300   1\\
4500    -1250   1\\
4500    -1200   1\\
4500    -1150   1\\
4500    -1100   1\\
4500    -1050   1\\
4500    -1000   1\\
4500    -950    1\\
4500    -900    1\\
4500    -850    1\\
4500    -800    1\\
4500    -750    1\\
4500    -700    1\\
4500    -650    1\\
4500    -600    1\\
4500    -550    1\\
4500    -500    1\\
4500    -450    1\\
4500    -400    2\\
4500    -350    2\\
4500    -300    2\\
4500    -250    2\\
4500    -200    2\\
4500    -150    2\\
4500    -100    3\\
4500    -50 3\\
4500    0   3\\
4500    50  3\\
4500    100 3\\
4500    150 3\\
4500    200 3\\
4500    250 3\\
4500    300 3\\
4500    350 3\\
4500    400 3\\
4500    450 3\\
4500    500 3\\
4500    550 1\\
4500    600 1\\
4500    650 1\\
4500    700 1\\
4500    750 1\\
4500    800 1\\
4500    850 1\\
4500    900 1\\
4500    950 1\\
4500    1000    1\\
4500    1050    1\\
4500    1100    1\\
4500    1150    1\\
4500    1200    1\\
4500    1250    1\\
4500    1300    1\\
4500    1350    1\\
4500    1400    1\\
4500    1450    1\\
4500    1500    1\\
4500    1550    1\\
4500    1600    1\\
4500    1650    1\\
4500    1700    1\\
4500    1750    1\\
4500    1800    1\\
4500    1850    1\\
4500    1900    1\\
4500    1950    1\\
4500    2000    1\\
5000    -2000   1\\
5000    -1950   1\\
5000    -1900   1\\
5000    -1850   1\\
5000    -1800   1\\
5000    -1750   1\\
5000    -1700   1\\
5000    -1650   1\\
5000    -1600   1\\
5000    -1550   1\\
5000    -1500   1\\
5000    -1450   1\\
5000    -1400   1\\
5000    -1350   1\\
5000    -1300   1\\
5000    -1250   1\\
5000    -1200   1\\
5000    -1150   1\\
5000    -1100   1\\
5000    -1050   1\\
5000    -1000   1\\
5000    -950    1\\
5000    -900    1\\
5000    -850    1\\
5000    -800    1\\
5000    -750    1\\
5000    -700    1\\
5000    -650    1\\
5000    -600    1\\
5000    -550    1\\
5000    -500    1\\
5000    -450    1\\
5000    -400    2\\
5000    -350    2\\
5000    -300    2\\
5000    -250    2\\
5000    -200    2\\
5000    -150    2\\
5000    -100    3\\
5000    -50 3\\
5000    0   3\\
5000    50  3\\
5000    100 3\\
5000    150 3\\
5000    200 3\\
5000    250 3\\
5000    300 3\\
5000    350 3\\
5000    400 3\\
5000    450 3\\
5000    500 3\\
5000    550 1\\
5000    600 1\\
5000    650 1\\
5000    700 1\\
5000    750 1\\
5000    800 1\\
5000    850 1\\
5000    900 1\\
5000    950 1\\
5000    1000    1\\
5000    1050    1\\
5000    1100    1\\
5000    1150    1\\
5000    1200    1\\
5000    1250    1\\
5000    1300    1\\
5000    1350    1\\
5000    1400    1\\
5000    1450    1\\
5000    1500    1\\
5000    1550    1\\
5000    1600    1\\
5000    1650    1\\
5000    1700    1\\
5000    1750    1\\
5000    1800    1\\
5000    1850    1\\
5000    1900    1\\
5000    1950    1\\
5000    2000    1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have two choices: (a) to assemble the legend manually (for example using `\addlegendimage`, might need some custom work + styles) or (b) to use a `colorbar` with a suitable option set.

I believe that you discarded option (b) because you do not want a continuos colorbar. However, there is the option `colorbar sampled line` which (a) samples the colorbar at discrete samples and (b) uses a scatter or line plot to visualize the colors. This appears to be what you need here -- provided that your image does not need additional (non-colorbar) legend entries. The advantage is that you get the color stuff for free.

Here is it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

% \usetikzlibrary{}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width = 7.5cm,height=5cm, 
view ={0}{90},
xmin=0,
xmax=5000,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-2000,
ymax=2000,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0,
zmax=5,
zmajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
%legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},
%    anchor=north,legend columns=0},
%legend entries={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar sampled line={scatter,only marks,mark=-,line width=5pt, samples at={1,2,3,4,5}},
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,
colormap/jet,
mesh/rows=11]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false] {%
%
0   -2000   1\\
0   -1950   1\\
0   -1900   1\\
0   -1850   1\\
0   -1800   1\\
0   -1750   1\\
0   -1700   1\\
0   -1650   1\\
0   -1600   1\\
0   -1550   1\\
0   -1500   1\\
0   -1450   1\\
0   -1400   1\\
0   -1350   1\\
0   -1300   1\\
0   -1250   1\\
0   -1200   1\\
0   -1150   1\\
0   -1100   1\\
0   -1050   1\\
0   -1000   1\\
0   -950    1\\
0   -900    1\\
0   -850    1\\
0   -800    1\\
0   -750    1\\
0   -700    1\\
0   -650    1\\
0   -600    1\\
0   -550    1\\
0   -500    1\\
0   -450    1\\
0   -400    1\\
0   -350    1\\
0   -300    1\\
0   -250    1\\
0   -200    5\\
0   -150    5\\
0   -100    5\\
0   -50 5\\
0   0   5\\
0   50  3\\
0   100 3\\
0   150 3\\
0   200 3\\
0   250 3\\
0   300 1\\
0   350 1\\
0   400 1\\
0   450 1\\
0   500 1\\
0   550 1\\
0   600 1\\
0   650 1\\
0   700 1\\
0   750 1\\
0   800 1\\
0   850 1\\
0   900 1\\
0   950 1\\
0   1000    1\\
0   1050    1\\
0   1100    1\\
0   1150    1\\
0   1200    1\\
0   1250    1\\
0   1300    1\\
0   1350    1\\
0   1400    1\\
0   1450    1\\
0   1500    1\\
0   1550    1\\
0   1600    1\\
0   1650    1\\
0   1700    1\\
0   1750    1\\
0   1800    1\\
0   1850    1\\
0   1900    1\\
0   1950    1\\
0   2000    1\\
500 -2000   1\\
500 -1950   1\\
500 -1900   1\\
500 -1850   1\\
500 -1800   1\\
500 -1750   1\\
500 -1700   1\\
500 -1650   1\\
500 -1600   1\\
500 -1550   1\\
500 -1500   1\\
500 -1450   1\\
500 -1400   1\\
500 -1350   1\\
500 -1300   1\\
500 -1250   1\\
500 -1200   1\\
500 -1150   1\\
500 -1100   1\\
500 -1050   1\\
500 -1000   1\\
500 -950    1\\
500 -900    1\\
500 -850    1\\
500 -800    1\\
500 -750    1\\
500 -700    1\\
500 -650    1\\
500 -600    1\\
500 -550    1\\
500 -500    1\\
500 -450    1\\
500 -400    1\\
500 -350    1\\
500 -300    1\\
500 -250    1\\
500 -200    5\\
500 -150    5\\
500 -100    5\\
500 -50 5\\
500 0   3\\
500 50  3\\
500 100 3\\
500 150 3\\
500 200 3\\
500 250 3\\
500 300 3\\
500 350 1\\
500 400 1\\
500 450 1\\
500 500 1\\
500 550 1\\
500 600 1\\
500 650 1\\
500 700 1\\
500 750 1\\
500 800 1\\
500 850 1\\
500 900 1\\
500 950 1\\
500 1000    1\\
500 1050    1\\
500 1100    1\\
500 1150    1\\
500 1200    1\\
500 1250    1\\
500 1300    1\\
500 1350    1\\
500 1400    1\\
500 1450    1\\
500 1500    1\\
500 1550    1\\
500 1600    1\\
500 1650    1\\
500 1700    1\\
500 1750    1\\
500 1800    1\\
500 1850    1\\
500 1900    1\\
500 1950    1\\
500 2000    1\\
1000    -2000   1\\
1000    -1950   1\\
1000    -1900   1\\
1000    -1850   1\\
1000    -1800   1\\
1000    -1750   1\\
1000    -1700   1\\
1000    -1650   1\\
1000    -1600   1\\
1000    -1550   1\\
1000    -1500   1\\
1000    -1450   1\\
1000    -1400   1\\
1000    -1350   1\\
1000    -1300   1\\
1000    -1250   1\\
1000    -1200   1\\
1000    -1150   1\\
1000    -1100   1\\
1000    -1050   1\\
1000    -1000   1\\
1000    -950    1\\
1000    -900    1\\
1000    -850    1\\
1000    -800    1\\
1000    -750    1\\
1000    -700    1\\
1000    -650    1\\
1000    -600    1\\
1000    -550    1\\
1000    -500    1\\
1000    -450    1\\
1000    -400    1\\
1000    -350    1\\
1000    -300    1\\
1000    -250    1\\
1000    -200    5\\
1000    -150    5\\
1000    -100    5\\
1000    -50 5\\
1000    0   3\\
1000    50  3\\
1000    100 3\\
1000    150 3\\
1000    200 3\\
1000    250 3\\
1000    300 3\\
1000    350 1\\
1000    400 1\\
1000    450 1\\
1000    500 1\\
1000    550 1\\
1000    600 1\\
1000    650 1\\
1000    700 1\\
1000    750 1\\
1000    800 1\\
1000    850 1\\
1000    900 1\\
1000    950 1\\
1000    1000    1\\
1000    1050    1\\
1000    1100    1\\
1000    1150    1\\
1000    1200    1\\
1000    1250    1\\
1000    1300    1\\
1000    1350    1\\
1000    1400    1\\
1000    1450    1\\
1000    1500    1\\
1000    1550    1\\
1000    1600    1\\
1000    1650    1\\
1000    1700    1\\
1000    1750    1\\
1000    1800    1\\
1000    1850    1\\
1000    1900    1\\
1000    1950    1\\
1000    2000    1\\
1500    -2000   1\\
1500    -1950   1\\
1500    -1900   1\\
1500    -1850   1\\
1500    -1800   1\\
1500    -1750   1\\
1500    -1700   1\\
1500    -1650   1\\
1500    -1600   1\\
1500    -1550   1\\
1500    -1500   1\\
1500    -1450   1\\
1500    -1400   1\\
1500    -1350   1\\
1500    -1300   1\\
1500    -1250   1\\
1500    -1200   1\\
1500    -1150   1\\
1500    -1100   1\\
1500    -1050   1\\
1500    -1000   1\\
1500    -950    1\\
1500    -900    1\\
1500    -850    1\\
1500    -800    1\\
1500    -750    1\\
1500    -700    1\\
1500    -650    1\\
1500    -600    1\\
1500    -550    1\\
1500    -500    1\\
1500    -450    1\\
1500    -400    1\\
1500    -350    1\\
1500    -300    1\\
1500    -250    1\\
1500    -200    2\\
1500    -150    3\\
1500    -100    3\\
1500    -50 3\\
1500    0   3\\
1500    50  3\\
1500    100 3\\
1500    150 3\\
1500    200 3\\
1500    250 3\\
1500    300 3\\
1500    350 3\\
1500    400 1\\
1500    450 1\\
1500    500 1\\
1500    550 1\\
1500    600 1\\
1500    650 1\\
1500    700 1\\
1500    750 1\\
1500    800 1\\
1500    850 1\\
1500    900 1\\
1500    950 1\\
1500    1000    1\\
1500    1050    1\\
1500    1100    1\\
1500    1150    1\\
1500    1200    1\\
1500    1250    1\\
1500    1300    1\\
1500    1350    1\\
1500    1400    1\\
1500    1450    1\\
1500    1500    1\\
1500    1550    1\\
1500    1600    1\\
1500    1650    1\\
1500    1700    1\\
1500    1750    1\\
1500    1800    1\\
1500    1850    1\\
1500    1900    1\\
1500    1950    1\\
1500    2000    1\\
2000    -2000   1\\
2000    -1950   1\\
2000    -1900   1\\
2000    -1850   1\\
2000    -1800   1\\
2000    -1750   1\\
2000    -1700   1\\
2000    -1650   1\\
2000    -1600   1\\
2000    -1550   1\\
2000    -1500   1\\
2000    -1450   1\\
2000    -1400   1\\
2000    -1350   1\\
2000    -1300   1\\
2000    -1250   1\\
2000    -1200   1\\
2000    -1150   1\\
2000    -1100   1\\
2000    -1050   1\\
2000    -1000   1\\
2000    -950    1\\
2000    -900    1\\
2000    -850    1\\
2000    -800    1\\
2000    -750    1\\
2000    -700    1\\
2000    -650    1\\
2000    -600    1\\
2000    -550    1\\
2000    -500    1\\
2000    -450    1\\
2000    -400    1\\
2000    -350    1\\
2000    -300    1\\
2000    -250    2\\
2000    -200    2\\
2000    -150    5\\
2000    -100    3\\
2000    -50 3\\
2000    0   3\\
2000    50  3\\
2000    100 3\\
2000    150 3\\
2000    200 3\\
2000    250 3\\
2000    300 3\\
2000    350 3\\
2000    400 1\\
2000    450 1\\
2000    500 1\\
2000    550 1\\
2000    600 1\\
2000    650 1\\
2000    700 1\\
2000    750 1\\
2000    800 1\\
2000    850 1\\
2000    900 1\\
2000    950 1\\
2000    1000    1\\
2000    1050    1\\
2000    1100    1\\
2000    1150    1\\
2000    1200    1\\
2000    1250    1\\
2000    1300    1\\
2000    1350    1\\
2000    1400    1\\
2000    1450    1\\
2000    1500    1\\
2000    1550    1\\
2000    1600    1\\
2000    1650    1\\
2000    1700    1\\
2000    1750    1\\
2000    1800    1\\
2000    1850    1\\
2000    1900    1\\
2000    1950    1\\
2000    2000    1\\
2500    -2000   1\\
2500    -1950   1\\
2500    -1900   1\\
2500    -1850   1\\
2500    -1800   1\\
2500    -1750   1\\
2500    -1700   1\\
2500    -1650   1\\
2500    -1600   1\\
2500    -1550   1\\
2500    -1500   1\\
2500    -1450   1\\
2500    -1400   1\\
2500    -1350   1\\
2500    -1300   1\\
2500    -1250   1\\
2500    -1200   1\\
2500    -1150   1\\
2500    -1100   1\\
2500    -1050   1\\
2500    -1000   1\\
2500    -950    1\\
2500    -900    1\\
2500    -850    1\\
2500    -800    1\\
2500    -750    1\\
2500    -700    1\\
2500    -650    1\\
2500    -600    1\\
2500    -550    1\\
2500    -500    1\\
2500    -450    1\\
2500    -400    1\\
2500    -350    1\\
2500    -300    2\\
2500    -250    2\\
2500    -200    2\\
2500    -150    5\\
2500    -100    3\\
2500    -50 3\\
2500    0   3\\
2500    50  3\\
2500    100 3\\
2500    150 3\\
2500    200 3\\
2500    250 3\\
2500    300 3\\
2500    350 3\\
2500    400 3\\
2500    450 1\\
2500    500 1\\
2500    550 1\\
2500    600 1\\
2500    650 1\\
2500    700 1\\
2500    750 1\\
2500    800 1\\
2500    850 1\\
2500    900 1\\
2500    950 1\\
2500    1000    1\\
2500    1050    1\\
2500    1100    1\\
2500    1150    1\\
2500    1200    1\\
2500    1250    1\\
2500    1300    1\\
2500    1350    1\\
2500    1400    1\\
2500    1450    1\\
2500    1500    1\\
2500    1550    1\\
2500    1600    1\\
2500    1650    1\\
2500    1700    1\\
2500    1750    1\\
2500    1800    1\\
2500    1850    1\\
2500    1900    1\\
2500    1950    1\\
2500    2000    1\\
3000    -2000   1\\
3000    -1950   1\\
3000    -1900   1\\
3000    -1850   1\\
3000    -1800   1\\
3000    -1750   1\\
3000    -1700   1\\
3000    -1650   1\\
3000    -1600   1\\
3000    -1550   1\\
3000    -1500   1\\
3000    -1450   1\\
3000    -1400   1\\
3000    -1350   1\\
3000    -1300   1\\
3000    -1250   1\\
3000    -1200   1\\
3000    -1150   1\\
3000    -1100   1\\
3000    -1050   1\\
3000    -1000   1\\
3000    -950    1\\
3000    -900    1\\
3000    -850    1\\
3000    -800    1\\
3000    -750    1\\
3000    -700    1\\
3000    -650    1\\
3000    -600    1\\
3000    -550    1\\
3000    -500    1\\
3000    -450    1\\
3000    -400    1\\
3000    -350    2\\
3000    -300    2\\
3000    -250    2\\
3000    -200    2\\
3000    -150    2\\
3000    -100    3\\
3000    -50 3\\
3000    0   3\\
3000    50  3\\
3000    100 3\\
3000    150 3\\
3000    200 3\\
3000    250 3\\
3000    300 3\\
3000    350 3\\
3000    400 3\\
3000    450 3\\
3000    500 1\\
3000    550 1\\
3000    600 1\\
3000    650 1\\
3000    700 1\\
3000    750 1\\
3000    800 1\\
3000    850 1\\
3000    900 1\\
3000    950 1\\
3000    1000    1\\
3000    1050    1\\
3000    1100    1\\
3000    1150    1\\
3000    1200    1\\
3000    1250    1\\
3000    1300    1\\
3000    1350    1\\
3000    1400    1\\
3000    1450    1\\
3000    1500    1\\
3000    1550    1\\
3000    1600    1\\
3000    1650    1\\
3000    1700    1\\
3000    1750    1\\
3000    1800    1\\
3000    1850    1\\
3000    1900    1\\
3000    1950    1\\
3000    2000    1\\
3500    -2000   1\\
3500    -1950   1\\
3500    -1900   1\\
3500    -1850   1\\
3500    -1800   1\\
3500    -1750   1\\
3500    -1700   1\\
3500    -1650   1\\
3500    -1600   1\\
3500    -1550   1\\
3500    -1500   1\\
3500    -1450   1\\
3500    -1400   1\\
3500    -1350   1\\
3500    -1300   1\\
3500    -1250   1\\
3500    -1200   1\\
3500    -1150   1\\
3500    -1100   1\\
3500    -1050   1\\
3500    -1000   1\\
3500    -950    1\\
3500    -900    1\\
3500    -850    1\\
3500    -800    1\\
3500    -750    1\\
3500    -700    1\\
3500    -650    1\\
3500    -600    1\\
3500    -550    1\\
3500    -500    1\\
3500    -450    1\\
3500    -400    1\\
3500    -350    2\\
3500    -300    2\\
3500    -250    2\\
3500    -200    2\\
3500    -150    2\\
3500    -100    3\\
3500    -50 3\\
3500    0   3\\
3500    50  3\\
3500    100 3\\
3500    150 3\\
3500    200 3\\
3500    250 3\\
3500    300 3\\
3500    350 3\\
3500    400 3\\
3500    450 3\\
3500    500 1\\
3500    550 1\\
3500    600 1\\
3500    650 1\\
3500    700 1\\
3500    750 1\\
3500    800 1\\
3500    850 1\\
3500    900 1\\
3500    950 1\\
3500    1000    1\\
3500    1050    1\\
3500    1100    1\\
3500    1150    1\\
3500    1200    1\\
3500    1250    1\\
3500    1300    1\\
3500    1350    1\\
3500    1400    1\\
3500    1450    1\\
3500    1500    1\\
3500    1550    1\\
3500    1600    1\\
3500    1650    1\\
3500    1700    1\\
3500    1750    1\\
3500    1800    1\\
3500    1850    1\\
3500    1900    1\\
3500    1950    1\\
3500    2000    1\\
4000    -2000   1\\
4000    -1950   1\\
4000    -1900   1\\
4000    -1850   1\\
4000    -1800   1\\
4000    -1750   1\\
4000    -1700   1\\
4000    -1650   1\\
4000    -1600   1\\
4000    -1550   1\\
4000    -1500   1\\
4000    -1450   1\\
4000    -1400   1\\
4000    -1350   1\\
4000    -1300   1\\
4000    -1250   1\\
4000    -1200   1\\
4000    -1150   1\\
4000    -1100   1\\
4000    -1050   1\\
4000    -1000   1\\
4000    -950    1\\
4000    -900    1\\
4000    -850    1\\
4000    -800    1\\
4000    -750    1\\
4000    -700    1\\
4000    -650    1\\
4000    -600    1\\
4000    -550    1\\
4000    -500    1\\
4000    -450    1\\
4000    -400    2\\
4000    -350    2\\
4000    -300    2\\
4000    -250    2\\
4000    -200    2\\
4000    -150    2\\
4000    -100    3\\
4000    -50 3\\
4000    0   3\\
4000    50  3\\
4000    100 3\\
4000    150 3\\
4000    200 3\\
4000    250 3\\
4000    300 3\\
4000    350 3\\
4000    400 3\\
4000    450 3\\
4000    500 1\\
4000    550 1\\
4000    600 1\\
4000    650 1\\
4000    700 1\\
4000    750 1\\
4000    800 1\\
4000    850 1\\
4000    900 1\\
4000    950 1\\
4000    1000    1\\
4000    1050    1\\
4000    1100    1\\
4000    1150    1\\
4000    1200    1\\
4000    1250    1\\
4000    1300    1\\
4000    1350    1\\
4000    1400    1\\
4000    1450    1\\
4000    1500    1\\
4000    1550    1\\
4000    1600    1\\
4000    1650    1\\
4000    1700    1\\
4000    1750    1\\
4000    1800    1\\
4000    1850    1\\
4000    1900    1\\
4000    1950    1\\
4000    2000    1\\
4500    -2000   1\\
4500    -1950   1\\
4500    -1900   1\\
4500    -1850   1\\
4500    -1800   1\\
4500    -1750   1\\
4500    -1700   1\\
4500    -1650   1\\
4500    -1600   1\\
4500    -1550   1\\
4500    -1500   1\\
4500    -1450   1\\
4500    -1400   1\\
4500    -1350   1\\
4500    -1300   1\\
4500    -1250   1\\
4500    -1200   1\\
4500    -1150   1\\
4500    -1100   1\\
4500    -1050   1\\
4500    -1000   1\\
4500    -950    1\\
4500    -900    1\\
4500    -850    1\\
4500    -800    1\\
4500    -750    1\\
4500    -700    1\\
4500    -650    1\\
4500    -600    1\\
4500    -550    1\\
4500    -500    1\\
4500    -450    1\\
4500    -400    2\\
4500    -350    2\\
4500    -300    2\\
4500    -250    2\\
4500    -200    2\\
4500    -150    2\\
4500    -100    3\\
4500    -50 3\\
4500    0   3\\
4500    50  3\\
4500    100 3\\
4500    150 3\\
4500    200 3\\
4500    250 3\\
4500    300 3\\
4500    350 3\\
4500    400 3\\
4500    450 3\\
4500    500 3\\
4500    550 1\\
4500    600 1\\
4500    650 1\\
4500    700 1\\
4500    750 1\\
4500    800 1\\
4500    850 1\\
4500    900 1\\
4500    950 1\\
4500    1000    1\\
4500    1050    1\\
4500    1100    1\\
4500    1150    1\\
4500    1200    1\\
4500    1250    1\\
4500    1300    1\\
4500    1350    1\\
4500    1400    1\\
4500    1450    1\\
4500    1500    1\\
4500    1550    1\\
4500    1600    1\\
4500    1650    1\\
4500    1700    1\\
4500    1750    1\\
4500    1800    1\\
4500    1850    1\\
4500    1900    1\\
4500    1950    1\\
4500    2000    1\\
5000    -2000   1\\
5000    -1950   1\\
5000    -1900   1\\
5000    -1850   1\\
5000    -1800   1\\
5000    -1750   1\\
5000    -1700   1\\
5000    -1650   1\\
5000    -1600   1\\
5000    -1550   1\\
5000    -1500   1\\
5000    -1450   1\\
5000    -1400   1\\
5000    -1350   1\\
5000    -1300   1\\
5000    -1250   1\\
5000    -1200   1\\
5000    -1150   1\\
5000    -1100   1\\
5000    -1050   1\\
5000    -1000   1\\
5000    -950    1\\
5000    -900    1\\
5000    -850    1\\
5000    -800    1\\
5000    -750    1\\
5000    -700    1\\
5000    -650    1\\
5000    -600    1\\
5000    -550    1\\
5000    -500    1\\
5000    -450    1\\
5000    -400    2\\
5000    -350    2\\
5000    -300    2\\
5000    -250    2\\
5000    -200    2\\
5000    -150    2\\
5000    -100    3\\
5000    -50 3\\
5000    0   3\\
5000    50  3\\
5000    100 3\\
5000    150 3\\
5000    200 3\\
5000    250 3\\
5000    300 3\\
5000    350 3\\
5000    400 3\\
5000    450 3\\
5000    500 3\\
5000    550 1\\
5000    600 1\\
5000    650 1\\
5000    700 1\\
5000    750 1\\
5000    800 1\\
5000    850 1\\
5000    900 1\\
5000    950 1\\
5000    1000    1\\
5000    1050    1\\
5000    1100    1\\
5000    1150    1\\
5000    1200    1\\
5000    1250    1\\
5000    1300    1\\
5000    1350    1\\
5000    1400    1\\
5000    1450    1\\
5000    1500    1\\
5000    1550    1\\
5000    1600    1\\
5000    1650    1\\
5000    1700    1\\
5000    1750    1\\
5000    1800    1\\
5000    1850    1\\
5000    1900    1\\
5000    1950    1\\
5000    2000    1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```